# AR Image Tracking Not Sensing Images in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I am developing an image tracking application in Unity 2020.3 using ARKit and AR Foundation. All I am trying to do is spawn cubes on different QR Codes.

I initially followed [this tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/project/create-a-marker-based-ar-app), but I couldn't get the image tracking working. By this I mean, no cubes spawn as if the Reference Library and image tracking isn't recognizing my images at all.

Here is my initial script, which I tried with the tutorial images and QR codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ARTrackedImageManager))]
public class TrackingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    ARTrackedImageManager imageManager;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject spawnablePrefab;
    GameObject spawnedObject;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        imageManager = GetComponent<ARTrackedImageManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(imageManager == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not find the image manager.");
        }
    }

    void OnEnable() => imageManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnChanged;

    void OnDisable() => imageManager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnChanged;

    void OnChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        foreach (ARTrackedImage newImage in eventArgs.added)
        {
             if(newImage.referenceImage.name == "arMarker1") // && trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                Debug.Log("Found Marker 1!");
                if (spawnedObject == null)
                {
                    SpawnPrefab(newImage.transform.position, newImage.transform.rotation);
                }
                    
                spawnedObject.transform.position = newImage.transform.position;
                spawnedObject.transform.rotation = newImage.transform.rotation;
            }
        }

        foreach (ARTrackedImage updatedImage in eventArgs.updated)
        {
            if (updatedImage.referenceImage.name.Equals("arMarker1") && updatedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
                if(spawnedObject != null)
                {
                    spawnedObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(updatedImage.transform.position, updatedImage.transform.rotation);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (ARTrackedImage removedImage in eventArgs.removed)
        {
            if (removedImage.referenceImage.name.Equals("arMarker1") && removedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.None)
            {
                if (spawnedObject != null)
                {
                    Destroy(spawnedObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void SpawnPrefab(Vector3 spawnPosition, Quaternion spawnRotation)
    {
        spawnedObject = Instantiate(spawnablePrefab, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
    }
}
```

Since then, I have tried multiple different approaches from different sources, and I still haven't been able to get it working.

Here is my script as it stands today, which is being tested with QR codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ARTrackedImageManager))]
public class TrackingManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    List<string> prefabs;

    ARTrackedImageManager imageManager;

    //Maps reference images to their associated prefabs.
    Dictionary<Guid, GameObject> imageToPrefab = new Dictionary<Guid, GameObject>();
    //Tracks currently instanciated prefabs.
    Dictionary<Guid, GameObject> instantiated = new Dictionary<Guid, GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        imageManager = GetComponent<ARTrackedImageManager>();

        prefabs = new List<string>();
        prefabs.Add("orange"); 
        prefabs.Add("green");
        prefabs.Add("blue");

        SetupPrefabs();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(imageManager == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not find the image manager.");
        }
    }
    
    void OnEnable() => imageManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnChanged;

    void OnDisable() => imageManager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnChanged;

    void OnChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        foreach (ARTrackedImage newImage in eventArgs.added)
        {
            if(imageToPrefab.TryGetValue(newImage.referenceImage.guid, out var prefab))
            {
                instantiated[newImage.referenceImage.guid] = Instantiate(prefab, newImage.transform);
            }
        }

        foreach (ARTrackedImage updatedImage in eventArgs.updated)
        {
            if(imageToPrefab.ContainsKey(updatedImage.referenceImage.guid))
            {
                instantiated[updatedImage.referenceImage.guid].transform.position = updatedImage.transform.position;
                instantiated[updatedImage.referenceImage.guid].transform.rotation = updatedImage.transform.rotation;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetupPrefabs()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<imageLib.count; i++)
        {
            imageToPrefab.Add(imageLib[i].guid, (GameObject)Resources.Load("/Prefabs/" + prefabs[i] + "Cube"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure what to try at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

(Edit 5/5: Posted Wrong Code Initially)

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch from using 2020.3 to 2021.3, and now everything works!